# EventInjector.KeyEvent not working on actual device in blackberry

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

1. I am developing a stress build of an application, where I need to have an infinite loop to simulate key press in blackberry. It has no problem when i tested it in an emulator but when I tested it in an actual blackberry device, the EventInjector.KeyEvent is not working. I already signed my application, but still it is not working on an actual device.

Comment: i found it, you need to set permission first for you application who need to use some interactions like key injections. this is the solution. navigate to this: Options==>Advance Options==>Applications==>[your app]==>Edit Permissions==>[configure]

Comment: Would you share result of your stress application to open source? :)

Comment: I don't know if I'm allowed to do that. It's up to my bosses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. It just need a little configuration on your device.

For OS version 5.0 below(e.g. BB9000, BB8900, BB8520, BB9630, BB9550, BB9700)
    Go to Options->Advance Options->Applications->Highlight AMX_IM_BB_v6 then press menu                   key->Select Edit Permissions->Allow Interactions->press menu key then save

For OS version 6.0 above(e.g. BB9800, BB9900)
    Go to Options->Application Management->AMX_IM_BB_V6->Edit Permissions
              ->AllowInteractions->press menu key then save